# How can I force a table to "wrap" at the page's margin?

Tags: tables, wrap

I created this table

```
The data can be distributed evenly over an interval of ${[-\pi,\pi]}$. It will
then become easier to calculate its Fourier series.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c|c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c }
  $x$ & -3.14 & -3.01 & -2.87 & -2.74 & -2.61 & -2.47 & -2.34 & -2.21 & -2.07 & -1.94 & -1.8 & -1.67 & -1.54 & -1.4 & -1.27 & -1.14 & -1.0 & -0.87 & -0.74 & -0.6 & -0.47 & -0.33 & -0.2 & -0.07 & 0.07 & 0.2 & 0.33 & 0.47 & 0.6 & 0.74 & 0.87 & 1.0 & 1.14 & 1.27 & 1.4 & 1.54 & 1.67 & 1.8 & 1.94 & 2.07 & 2.21 & 2.34 & 2.47 & 2.61 & 2.74 & 2.87 & 3.01 & 3.14 \\
  $v$ & 0.009 & 0.237 & 0.315 & 0.582 & 0.468 & 0.71 & 0.451 & 0.62 & 0.307 & 0.413 & 0.216 & 0.316 & 0.358 & 0.453 & 0.697 & 0.637 & 0.842 & 0.59 & 0.69 & 0.241 & 0.231 & -0.166 & -0.172 & -0.351 & -0.351 & -0.324 & -0.424 & -0.308 & -0.552 & -0.391 & -0.661 & -0.41 & -0.56 & -0.268 & -0.299 & -0.117 & -0.093 & -0.106 & -0.023 & -0.175 & 0.022 & -0.163 & 0.121 & -0.079 & 0.145 & -0.092 & -0.046 & -0.277
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

But it looks like this in the output:

[image]

How can I get the table to "wrap" at the page's edge so that all the data can be seen across multiple lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot put elephant into suitcase ... see, if the folowing broke of your table rows is acceptable for you:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
The data can be distributed evenly over an interval of ${[-\pi,\pi]}$. It will
then become easier to calculate its Fourier series.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c | *{10}{r} @{}}
$x$ & -3.14 & -3.01 & -2.87 & -2.74 & -2.61 & -2.47 & -2.34 & -2.21 & -2.07 & -1.94 \\
    & -1.8  & -1.67 & -1.54 & -1.4  & -1.27 & -1.14 & -1.0  & -0.87 & -0.74 & -0.6  \\
    & -0.47 & -0.33 & -0.2  & -0.07 &  0.07 &  0.2  & 0.33  &  0.47 &  0.6  & 0.74  \\
    &  0.87 &  1.0  &  1.14 &  1.27 &  1.4  &  1.54 & 1.67  &  1.8  &  1.94 & 2.07  \\
    &  2.21 &  2.34 &  2.47 &  2.61 &  2.74 &  2.87 & 3.01  &  3.14 \\
    \addlinespace
$v$ & 0.009 & 0.237 & 0.315 & 0.582 & 0.468 &  0.71 & 0.451 &  0.62 & 0.307 & 0.413 \\
    & 0.216 & 0.316 & 0.358 & 0.453 & 0.697 & 0.637 & 0.842 & 0.59  & 0.69  & 0.241 \\
    & 0.231 &-0.166 &-0.172 &-0.351 &-0.351 &-0.324 &-0.424 &-0.308 &-0.552 &-0.391 \\ 
    &-0.661 & -0.41 & -0.56 &-0.268 &-0.299 &-0.117 &-0.093 &-0.106 &-0.023 &-0.175 \\
    & 0.022 &-0.163 & 0.121 &-0.079 & 0.145 &-0.092 &-0.046 & -0.277
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ups, something went wrong ... i will correct asap.